# Single Success Callback with RxJS Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

How can I have a single success callback with observables while allowing each single observable to have its own success/error block?  I have a dynamic list of AJAX calls which need to be made and each one requires it's on callback method.  I'd also would like to have a single callback method after every AJAX call completes.  I've tried using `zip`, but AJAX calls are called twice.

Example:

```
var possibleRequest1 = Observable.create(() => {}).subscribe(_ => {
    //Must have a success callback
});
var possibleRequest2 = Observable.create(() => {}).subscribe(_ => {
    //Must have a success callback
});
var possibleRequest3 = Observable.create(() => {}).subscribe(_ => {
    //Must have a success callback
});

//User 1 might need to make requests 1 and 2
var dynamicRequstList = [possibleRequest1, possibleRequest2];
//User 2 might need to make all three requests
var dynamicRequstList = [possibleRequest1, possibleRequest2, possibleRequest3];

zip(...dynamicRequestList)
.subscribe(() => {
    //Need a callback after all requests are complete.
});
```

Comment: You don't want to use HttpClient ?

Comment: How can HttpClient make this possible?

Comment: It would make the code simpler, cleaner and easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) from rxjs. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgsihc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts) example how use forkJoin on the example of your question.

**service.ts**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

requestList1$ = new Subject();
requestList2$ = new Subject();

getDynamicRequstList1() {
    forkJoin(
      this.getItems1(),
      this.getItems2()
    ).subscribe(res => this.requestList1$.next(res));
}

getDynamicRequstList2() {
    forkJoin(
      this.getItems1(),
      this.getItems2(),
      this.getItems3()
    ).subscribe(res => this.requestList2$.next(res));
}  

getItems1(): Observable<any> {
    return of({
      item1: 'Item 1'
    });
}  

getItems2(): Observable<any> {
    return of({
      item1: 'Item 2'
    });
  }  

getItems3(): Observable<any> {
    return of({
      item1: 'Item 3'
    });
}
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private service: AppService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.requestList1$.subscribe(res => console.log('RES 1:::', res))
  this.service.requestList2$.subscribe(res => console.log('RES 2:::', res))
}
```

Comment: It appears I need to change `zip` to `forkJoin` and the request `subscribe` to `pipe`.

Comment: I just updated answer, you can view here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgsihc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts.